# Google Custom Search Engine Schema.org structured data and returned results through API

Tags: schema.org, google-custom-search, google-search-api, rdfa, structured-data

Here is my markup with rich snippets

```html
<div vocab="http://schema.org" typeof="GovernmentOrganization">
<p>
    <span property="logo"><img src="http://www.place.com/image.png" class="logo"/></span>
    <span class="h2" property="name">Department Of Stuff And Things</span><br />
    <span class="h4" property="department">State Agency</span><br />
    <a href="http://www.place.com" class="h4 text-primary" property="url">http://www.place.com</a>
</p>

<strong>Locations:</strong><br /><br />                 
    <div property="location" typeof="GovernmentOffice">
        <p property="location" typeof="PostalAddress">
            Main Office<br />
            <span property="streetAddress">555 Something Street Apt 2</span><br />
            <span property="addressLocality">Jacksonville</span> 
            <span property="addressRegion">FL</span> 
            <span property="postalCode">11111</span><br />
            <span property="addressCountry">US</span>
        </p>
    </div>

<strong>Services:</strong><br /><br />
<div property="hasOfferCatalog" typeof="OfferCatalog">
        <div property="itemListElement" typeof="GovernmentService">
            <p>
                <strong><span property="name">Service 1</span></strong><br />
                <span property="category">Web Based</span><br />
                <span property="description">Get Some stuff and things</span><br />
                <a href="https://www.place.com/Service1" property="url">https://www.place.com/Service1</a><br />
            </p>
        </div>
        <div property="itemListElement" typeof="GovernmentService">
            <p>
                <strong><span property="name">Apply For Benefits</span></strong><br />
                <span property="category">Phone Based</span><br />
                <span property="description">This service helps you apply for the benefits you deserve</span><br />
                <a href="https://www.place.com/Service2" property="url">https://www.place.com/Service1</a><br />
            </p>
        </div>
</div>
```

The structured data testing tool seems to organize and validate everything appropriately, Including my small collection of services (OfferCatalog). When doing a request to the Custom Search API and tacking on the :more:pagemap:GovernmentOrganization things seem to be OK and I get results I expect. But the JSON object for pagemap only includes the first level of my organization:

```json
"pagemap": {
"GovernmentOrganization": [
 {
  "name": "Department Of Stuff And Things",
  "department": "State Agency",
  "url": "http://www.place.com"
 },
```

Any ideas on why my related objects (GovernmentOffice / locations / OfferCatalog / GovernmentServices) are not being including? Is there a better way to organize and structure this for Google?

Comment: Would you show the precise steps and URL that you are using to gen the pagemap? I am using your data with a different processor and getting a JSON-LD doc that is consistent with the RDFa.

Comment: I let google index my page to create the pagemap. I used structured data test tool to verify before the crawl was initiated https://developers.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool. But ultimately I'm leaving the pagemap up to Google's crawler. Do you think we would have better results by creating and submitting the pagemap ourselves? I do have a test page out there though http://customsearchweb20160302094014.azurewebsites.net it has one real entry and 3 test entries. I will not be doing multiple agencies on one page for production, I did it simply to test what comes out the other end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the Google:

> I believe you are seeing only one value of a attribute in JSON API.
>
> I would like to update you that as per the design in JSON API we show only one attribute value, while in XML we show all values.
>
> We already have a feature request #16696973 to display all the attribute values in JSON API. Currently I don't have an ETA when it will be implemented.
>
> As a workaround you have to use XML API.

Answer (score 0):

Consider this approach. Include the following `JSON-LD` script in the document. It can go anywhere but consider placing it before the `RDFa` DIV:

```
<script type="application/ld+json" id="">
{
"@context":
    {
      "@vocab": "http://schema.org/",
      "@base": "http://www.place.com/"
    },
"@graph": [
    {
      "@id": "_:ub220bL18C41",
      "@type": "PostalAddress",
      "addressCountry": "US",
      "addressLocality": "Jacksonville",
      "addressRegion": "FL",
      "postalCode": "11111",
      "streetAddress": "555 Something Street Apt 2"
    },
    {
      "@id": "_:ub220bL4C1",
      "@type": "GovernmentOrganization",
      "department": "State Agency",
      "hasOfferCatalog": {
        "@id": "_:ub220bL6C40"
      },
      "location": {
        "@id": "_:ub220bL17C33"
      },
      "logo": "",
      "name": "Department Of Stuff And Things",
      "url": "http://www.place.com"
    },
    {
      "@id": "_:ub220bL17C33",
      "@type": "GovernmentOffice",
      "location": {
        "@id": "_:ub220bL18C41"
      }
    },
    {
      "@id": "_:ub220bL6C40",
      "@type": "OfferCatalog",
      "itemListElement": [
        {
          "@id": "_:ub220bL12C17"
        },
        {
          "@id": "_:ub220bL7C48"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "@id": "_:ub220bL12C17",
      "@type": "GovernmentService",
      "category": "Web Based",
      "description": "Get Some stuff and things",
      "name": "Service 1",
      "url": "https://www.place.com/Service1"
    },
    {
      "@id": "_:ub220bL7C48",
      "@type": "GovernmentService",
      "category": "Phone Based",
      "description": "This service helps you apply for the benefits you deserve",
      "name": "Apply For Benefits",
      "url": "https://www.place.com/Service2"
    }
  ]
}
</script>
```

You'll want to change `@base` to your site and decide how to organize your directory structure to manage your identifiers. Then change each blank node to the appropriate identifier. Then minimize the JSON-LD.

The JSON-LD is semantically identical to the RDFa. As such, you will be able to analyze the Google `pagemap` and decide which strategy works better for you. I don't expect Google to penalize the page if the `JSON-LD` is semantically identical to the `HTML/RDFa` markup.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, i'll get my example site updated today and have Google crawl it (that could take another 24 hours).

Comment: So I tried the Json-ld, and removed the other test agencies on the page. Search console showed the script tag in the downloaded HTTP response. I checked again this morning (because two days have passed now) and the response is still the same. The structured data shows Government Organization and it's properties, but no other objects are included in the structured data. I also saw that my original vocab = was http://www.schema.org I fixed it by adding a trailing /. I resubmitted the page for index with the new / and no Json-ld. Does google only support a small number of schema.org definitions?

Comment: Let's wait to see your results based on properly setting the vocab (I should have caught that error when I first looked at your RDFa). TTBOMK Google does not discriminate when indexing schema terms. ITMT, please double check that your <script> (based on my proposal) is properly parse on GSDTT. Hopefully, one of these variations will be different from the others, and we then can decide which works best.

Comment: Sorry for the lack of update, the last index request took 3 days to fulfill. Even with the corrected vocab I still only get the top level object, no relationships persist. I've sent in a question to the Google Site Search (as we actually do pay for the service) support. I'll continue to update this thread if we make progress.

Comment: I am surprised by the result. Please post back the Google-explanation so we all can learn how to do this better.

Comment: I heard back from them today, they said that the JSON api will only return one attribute value while the XML results will display all.